# How to reshape multiple time-series signals for use with sns.tsplot?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, reshape, seaborn

I'm trying to reshape data that looks like this:

```
   t  y0  y1  y2
0  0  -1   0   1
1  1   0   1   2
2  2   1   2   3
3  3   2   3   4
4  4   3   4   5
```

into something like this:

```
    t  trial signal  value
 0  0  0     y       -1
 1  0  1     y        0
 2  0  2     y        1
 3  1  0     y        0
 4  1  1     y        1
 5  1  2     y        2
 6  2  0     y        1
 7  2  1     y        2
 8  2  2     y        3
 9  3  0     y        2
10  3  1     y        3
11  3  2     y        4
12  4  0     y        3
13  4  1     y        4
14  4  2     y        5
```

so that I can feed it into `sns.tsplot`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

fig = plt.figure()
num_points = 5

# Create some dummy line signals and assemble a data frame
t = np.arange(num_points)
y0 = t - 1
y1 = t
y2 = t + 1
df = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack((t, y0, y1, y2)).transpose(), columns=['t', 'y0', 'y1', 'y2'])
print(df)

# Do some magic transformations
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['t'])
print(df)

# Plot the time-series data
sns.tsplot(time="t", value="value", unit="trial", condition="signal", data=df, ci=[68, 95])

plt.savefig("dummy.png")
plt.close()
```

I'm hoping to achieve this for lines:

[image]

https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.tsplot.html
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) for reshaping, get first and second char by [indexing with str](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str) and last [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with reordering columns:

```
df1 = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['t'])
#create helper Series
variable = df1['variable']
#extract second char, convert to int
df1['trial'] = variable.str[1].astype(int)
#extract first char
df1['signal'] = variable.str[0]
#sort values by column t, reset index
df1 = df1.sort_values('t').reset_index(drop=True)
#reorder columns
df1 = df1[['t','trial','signal','value']]
print df1
    t trial signal  value
0   0     0      y     -1
1   0     1      y      0
2   0     2      y      1
3   1     0      y      0
4   1     1      y      1
5   1     2      y      2
6   2     0      y      1
7   2     1      y      2
8   2     2      y      3
9   3     0      y      2
10  3     1      y      3
11  3     2      y      4
12  4     0      y      3
13  4     1      y      4
14  4     2      y      5
```

Another solution, if all values in column `signal` are only `y`:

```
#remove y from column name, first value of column names is same
df.columns = df.columns[:1].tolist() + [int(col[1]) for col in df.columns[1:]]
print df
   t  0  1  2
0  0 -1  0  1
1  1  0  1  2
2  2  1  2  3
3  3  2  3  4
4  4  3  4  5

df1 = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['t'], var_name=['trial'])
#all values in column signal are y
df1['signal'] = 't'
#sort values by column t, reset index
df1 = df1.sort_values('t').reset_index(drop=True)
#reorder columns
df1 = df1[['t','trial','signal','value']]
print df1
    t trial signal  value
0   0     0      t     -1
1   0     1      t      0
2   0     2      t      1
3   1     0      t      0
4   1     1      t      1
5   1     2      t      2
6   2     0      t      1
7   2     1      t      2
8   2     2      t      3
9   3     0      t      2
10  3     1      t      3
11  3     2      t      4
12  4     0      t      3
13  4     1      t      4
14  4     2      t      5
```

Comment: omg, you answered that SO fast!  this works, but is there not a simpler transformation? i feel like this has to be a very common usage.

Comment: I think `melt` here is the best option. But you can use instead `melt` something like `print df.set_index('t').stack().reset_index(name='value').rename(columns={'level_1':'variable'})`, but it is more complicated.

Comment: this doesn't seem to scale to any number of trials

Comment: Can you explain more?